# how to get current width and height of turtle screen

Tags: python, responsive-design, turtle-graphics

I used `screen.setup()` to setup the screen but when the user resizes the screen
how can I get the changes so I can make app responsive to resizing
I need to change that integers to `screen_width-20`:

```
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(height=600,width=800)
```

this is the version I implemented

```
#collision with wall
    if ball.ycor() > 280 or ball.ycor() < -280:
        ball.bounce_y()
```

what I want to implement is

```
#collision with wall
    if ball.ycor() >screen_height-20 or ball.ycor() < -(screen_height-20):
        ball.bounce_y()
```

Comment: Doesnt screen.window_height() return height of your screen? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#using-screen-events

Comment: yeah it returned and using them worked.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`turtle.window_height()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.window_height) method.

From the documentation:

> #### `turtle.window_height()`
>
> Return the height of the turtle window.
>
> ```
> >>> screen.window_height()
> 480
> ```